# convergence related to chordal metric

Tags: complex-analysis

**Suppose that $\Omega$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{f_n:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}^*\}$ is a sequence of meromorphic functions on $\Omega$, where $\mathbb{C}^*$ is the extended complex plane endowed with the chordal metric and $\Omega$ endowed with the usual euclidean metric. Suppose that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Prove that $f$ is either meromorphic on $\Omega$ or identically $\infty$.**

Let $\sigma(z,w)=\frac{2|z-w|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|w|^2}}$ be the chordal metric on $\mathbb{C}^*$.

I think that the key point of the proof is the following claim:

Suppose that $f(z_0)\neq \infty$. We claim that there is a ball $B(z_0, \epsilon)$ and a constant $M$ such that $f_n$ is analytic in $B(z_0, \epsilon)$ and $|f_n(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\in B(z_0,\epsilon)$ and all $n$ sufficiently large.

Fix $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $\sigma(f_n(z_0),f(z_0))<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Since $\{f_n\}$ is a normal family, it is uniformly equicontinuous. Thus, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\sigma(f_n(z),f_n(z_0))<\epsilon$ for all $n$ and all $z\in \overline{B(z_0,\delta)}$, and so

$$\sigma(f_n(z),f(z_0))\leq \sigma(f_n(z),f_n(z_0))+\sigma(f_n(z_0),f(z_0))<2\epsilon$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large. Now note that if $f_n(z)=\infty$ for some $z$ , then $\sigma(f_n(z),f(z_0))=2/\sqrt{1+|f(z_0)|^2}$. Therefore, if we choose $\epsilon < 1/\sqrt{1+|f(z_0)|^2}$, then $f_n(z)\neq \infty$ in $\overline{B(z_0,\delta)}$.

Since the chordal metric is equivalent to Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{C}$, we see that for all $n$ sufficiently large, and for all $z\in B(z_0, \delta)$, we have $|f_n(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon.$ In other words, there is a ball $B(z_0, \delta)$ and a constant $M$ such that $f_n$ is analytic in $B(z_0, \epsilon)$ and $|f_n(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\in B(z_0,\epsilon)$ and all $n$ sufficiently large.

Now, on this ball $B(z_0,\delta)$ we have $\{f_n\}$ analytic and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $B(z_0,\delta)$ (with respect to Euclidean metric). Thus $f$ is analytic on $B(z_0,\delta)$.

Now my question is: is there anything wrong to my proof and is there a better way to prove this? Thanks

Comment: I think what you've shown is that the set of points where $f$ is analytic is an open set. That doesn't contradict the possibility of a non-isolated pole (nor there being an essential singularity), that I can see. Rather, try to show that unless $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)=\infty$ for all $z$, then every $z_0$ such that $f_n(z_0)\to\infty$ has a punctured neighborhood where $f_n(z)\not\to\infty$.